# Do large HTTP uploads still get an IIS log entry if aborted?

Tags: iis, logging, http, upload

Do (large) HTTP POSTs still get an IIS log entry if aborted, disrupted, or timed out before completing the upload (body of the HTTP request)? I'm trying to debug complaints of intermittent uploads that don't reach 100% in transfer, the IIS logs are quite long, and it'd be great to know if failed uploads of this nature will even show up these logs. This is IIS7 specifically.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

There is almost always an entry recorded as long as it successfully started the request.  However, the logs in C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR will sometimes catch the errors that occur earlier in the pipeline.  A timeout is different though and isn't an IIS error, so it should show in the logs.

For log file mining, check out Log Parser.   Very powerful for these type of situations.  A bit of a learning curve, especially if you don't know SQL syntax already, but well worth the time if you have to do this type of troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

I found the request with 504 result in the location C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR.
The s-reason field had "Request_Cancelled" for such requests